# How to get last day of the month in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I would like to make a function that input a NSDate and output the last date of the month. Do you guys know how to do it in Cocoa?

Answer (score 9):

It's the day before the first day of the next month. Add a month, set the day to 1, subtract a day. For setting the day to 1, you'll find it easier to go via NSCalendar. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725690/nsdate-for-first-day-of-the-month) for details.

Comment: +1 The universal answer.  Always right.  Always works.  Language, platform and framework agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing date computations, you should always use NSCalendar and related classes, because that's the only way to be forward-compatible with changes to calendars, support for non-"standard" calendars, and so on.

Read the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) section on [Calendrical Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) to get an idea of how these classes work together.